# Reduce stacktrace of executing frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack, stack-trace

I'm doing my best to not be vague here and this all could be solved with a while loop, but as an exercise I've gone against the best practice of using a while loop in hopes to learn something new.

I'm re-learning some basics of CPU architecture, and thought it'd be a fun project to implement CPU emulation with "actual" `JMP` logic, or as close to it as possible in software.

However, I'm getting stuck on a rendering process of said logic.
The code is *(according to my best judgement)* irrelevant to the problem but to avoid a back and fourth, the logic is as follows:

```
.LDA 0220
.ASL
.BCC FA
```

All this does it check a register, executes a bit shift to the left and jumps to memory address `FA` if a status flag is set correctly, if not it will jump back to `.LDA` and check the registers again.

The implementation in python does the same with a recursive function of each step in the code. Needless to say, this is beyond best practices but I thought it'd be a fun experiment in recursion and call-order.

If my math checks out, I end up with 16 280 recursive calls before python simply halts, and after 3 seconds or so just quits back out to the command prompt.

I've done `sys.setrecursionlimit(self.dotcount*self.linecount)` in a dirty attempt to increase the recursionlimit, and the goal here was to be able to execute 81 600 recursions *(340x240 pixels, one recursive call per pixel rougly)*.

according to [What is the maximum recursion depth in Python, and how to increase it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it) this is a bad idea, since the frames are pretty big, so my attempt to remedy this was:

```py
for tb in inspect.stack():
    tb.frame.clear()
```

I've also tried (to no prevail) to use `traceback.clear_frames(tb)`.
The dead end hits me with `RuntimeError: cannot clear an executing frame`.

My last resort/question is: Is it possible to reduce the executing frame to allow for more recursive calls that I know have a happy ending? I can't see that I'm even close to running out of RAM and the application isn't running even close to noticeably slow *(I was expecting a slow down at some point)*.

If so, how do I free up the stack trace or increase the recursion depth further?

Answer (score 1):

So Python itself doesn't have a mechanism to do tail recursion directly. However, there are some interesting [tail-recursion decorators](https://chrispenner.ca/posts/python-tail-recursion) which should help quite a bit. They work by editing the call stack before entering a recursive call again. Very clever!